# Android - More efficient method to read a big text file

Tags: java, android, string, text

I've a big txt file (1.5 Mb) as private resource in my Android Application.
The file is structured like this:

```
"A1|A2|A3|A4#B1|B2|B3|B4#C1|C2|C3|C4#..."
```

where A1, A2, A3, B1... are alphanumerical strings. I need to create an object for each group of strings, something like this:

```
MyObject objA = new MyObject("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4");
MyObject objB = new MyObject("B1", "B2", "B3", "B4");
...
```

I've developed a reader class in order to read this file... but it looks a bit slow.
Here it is:

```
public class TextFileReader {

    private static Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
    private InputStream stream;
    private InputStreamReader reader;
    private StringBuffer buffer;

    public TextFileReader(Context c, String s) {
        try {
            this.stream = c.openFileInput(s);
            this.reader = new InputStreamReader(this.stream, charset);
            this.buffer = new StringBuffer();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }

    public String readNextSubstring(char div) throws IOException {
        buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
        int i;
        char c;
        while ((i = reader.read()) > -1) {
            c = (char) i;
            if (c == div) break;
            buffer.append(c);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

I use `TextFileReader` in this way:

```
TextFileReader reader = new TextFileReader(context, "big_file.txt");

//First group
String group = reader.readNextSubstring('#');
String[] info = group.split("\\|");
MyObject objA = new MyObject(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]);

//Second group
group = reader.readNextSubstring('#');
info = group.split("\\|");
MyObject objB = new MyObject(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]);

//Obviously this is done in a while loop :)
...
```

What do you think about this method? Could it be structured in a more efficient way?
 I don't care about space, I care about time (the emulator takes a LOT of time in order to read the file)

Comment: why you don't restructure your file to use json ? is already made and it's extremely faster. Anyway a nice way to do this is using BuffedReader. Try to read this the info is all there.http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/PerfTuning/

Comment: My first reaction is, why are you doing this?  Put the data in a sqlite db.

Comment: I can't use a sqlite db because the data are in a remote server. And android's support for accessing a remote database really sucks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find one simple tweak that can speed you up simply by improving how much time you spend on doing this: `group.split("\\|");`

The way java does it is that for each time you run this line, it will compile a new `regex`.

If you do this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|");
TextFileReader reader = new TextFileReader(context, "big_file.txt");

while (reader.hasMoreData) 
{
  String group = reader.readNextSubstring('#');
  String[] info = pattern.split(group);
  MyObject objA = new MyObject(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[3]);
  ...
}
```

This will reduce the time it takes to compile the pattern - which can be quite considerable for your amount of data.

Also, 1.5MB is not that much, perhaps loading it all to memory using a `BufferedReader` will probably improve your performance even more.